# dynamically add/remove image in vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

```js
var loaderGif = "https://www.tietennis.com/img/loaders/LoaderIcon.gif"

var processingImageUrl = '<img id="imgProcessing" src="' + loaderGif + '" />'

$(document).on("click", "input[name='PermissionID']", function() {
    var PermissionCheckBox = $(this)[0];

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url:    "https://httpbin.org/post",
        cache:  false,
        async:  true,
        beforeSend: function(xhr, opts) {
            $(PermissionCheckBox).after(processingImageUrl);
        },
        success: function(result) {
            $(PermissionCheckBox).parent().find('#imgProcessing').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
             Check me:
             <input name="PermissionID" type="checkbox" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I was actually trying to convert the jQuery code to vue.js.

I am trying to find a way if I could put the image with checkbox on click in vue.js.

I tried below code, but now sure how could I use event passed from checkbox to add image and remove it

```
updatePermission(roleModulePermissionID, event) {
}
```

Can you suggest something for this?

Comment: Hm.. Where's the Vue on this? There doesn't seem nothing related to vue on this. What is it?

Comment: Yeah, in Vue, this'd be a simple `v-if` on the element, but there's no Vue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue, you (optimally) don't directly manipulate the DOM. You manipulate the `data` and configure the template to react to that data according to what you need.

To create multiple rows, use `v-for`.

So, for instance, **instead of adding and removing** a "loading image", you would create an `<img>` whose **display depended on some flag from your `data`**, say `permission.loading`:

```html
<img v-show="permission.loading" :src="loadingImg">
```

That way, when you set `permission.loading` to `true`, the loading image will show. When you set `permission.loading` to `false` it will hide.

Since you want to show it while the Ajax is performing, set `permission.loading` to `true` before calling the Ajax (the `fetch()` below) and set `permission.loading` to `false` when it completes.

**Full demo below**.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    loadingImg: "https://www.tietennis.com/img/loaders/LoaderIcon.gif", // for demo purposes
    permissions: [{
      id: 1,
      label: 'Permission to Take off',
      ticked: false,
      loading: false,
      postURL: "https://httpbin.org/post?take-off" // demo URL
    },{
      id: 2,
      label: 'Permission to Board',
      ticked: true,
      loading: false,
      postURL: "https://httpbin.org/post?board" // demo URL
    },{
      id: 3,
      label: 'Permission to Land',
      ticked: false,
      loading: false,
      postURL: "https://httpbin.org/post?land" // demo URL
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    updatePermission(permission) {
      permission.loading = true; // set loading and image will be shown
      fetch(permission.postURL, {method: "POST", body: {}})
        .then(() => permission.loading = false); // setting to false will make it disappear
    }
  }
})
```

```css
img { height: 17px; margin-bottom: -1px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="permission in permissions">
      <td>
        <label>
          {{ permission.label }}:
          <input name="PermissionID" type="checkbox" :value="permission.id" @change="updatePermission(permission)" v-model="permission.ticked" :disabled="permission.loading">
        </label>
        <img v-show="permission.loading" :src="loadingImg">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I also would add a `:disabled="permission.loading"` to prevent another click when it is loading.

Comment: actually there will be many checkboxes in the table which are rendering dynamically. Can u please suggest for that?

Comment: You can use `v-for` for that. Gimme a sec.

Comment: Updated. Check it out.

Comment: Working perfectly. Only one thing left, My image has src property defined like this. `<img v-if="ModulePermission.loading" :src="this.$root.domain_Name + 'Images/ajax-loader.gif'" />` Problem I think comes when the checkbox is clicked and it updates the loading property in the component and that time I get the error: **Cannot read property 'domain_Name' of undefined** but this is not the case at the time of load or at the time of click. I can confirm that I am using same property to concatenate post url.

Comment: There is no problem if the url is this: https://www.tietennis.com/img/loaders/LoaderIcon.gif Also there is no problem in other components as I am using this same code. I am assuming that it is 2 way process and that's why something is happening.

Comment: Try using `$root` without `this`, like: `:src="$root.domain_Name + 'Images/ajax-loader.gif'" `

Comment: any idea about : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460260/inform-user-that-message-is-still-being-typed

Comment: Seems good.. You could maybe do some sort of "debounce", to not send requests every typed char, but once every 4s, and if the other part doesn't receive a notification in 5s it stops displaying that the other one is typing.  Anyway, it looks cgood

Comment: Do I have an event called whisper as shown here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#client-events ? I am using vue.js and laravel 5.6.7

Comment: That seems proper. Though I think you should paste it there in the question. I like to help but I know Vue.js more than Laravel... So I think I can't help you much in this one.. sorry...

Comment: can u please suggest in vue.js only?

Comment: But your code actually seems to work. Do you encounter any problem using it?